# Round down to nearest 5 minutes

Tags: shell, date, sed, awk, grep

The date command returns the current date. I want the nearest 5 minute interval. For e.g.

```
# date
Thu Mar 15 16:06:42 IST 2012
```

In this case I want to return ...

```
Mar 15 16:05:00
```

Is it possible in the shell script? or is there any one liner for this?

**Update:**

the date is in this format...

```
2012-03-10 12:59:59
```

**Latest update:**

The following command works as expected. Thanks for the response.

```
head r_SERVER_2012-03-10-12-55-00 | awk -F'^' '{print $7}' |  awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d:00\n", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'
```

Correct result:

```
2012-03-10 12:55:00
```

But I want to show other fields as well other than date. The following does not work:

```
head r_SERVER_2012-03-10-12-55-00 | awk -F'^' '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}' |  awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d:00\n", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'
```

Wrong result:

```
565 14718:00:00
```

It should be ...

```
565 123 2012-03-10 12:55:00 country
```

Comment: Just for the fun of it, in PowerShell: `Get-Date ((([long]((Get-Date '2012-03-10 12:59:59').ticks/3e9))*[long]3e9))`.

Comment: Stop adding more to your question. I think you meant to ask about this in a chat room, seeing as how you seem to want a discussion about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date | awk '{split($4, a, ":"); printf "%s %s %s:%02d:00", $2, $3, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'
```

Comment: Actually the date is in this format... "2012-03-10 12:59:59". The format given in the question was just an example.

Comment: echo "2012-03-10 12:59:59" | awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d:00", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'

Comment: As nice as this is, it doesn't round things up to the next day.  `2012-03-10 23:59:59` should be rounded to `2012-03-11 00:00;00`.

Comment: @ghoti, it's meant to round down.

Comment: @dbaupp - "round" means "go to nearest integer".  What you're talking about is "truncate".  The OP said "nearest 5 minute interval".

Comment: @ghoti, sorry to seem rude, but "round down" (in the title) also means "truncate", and the second example given seems to indicate that truncate is the desired functionality.

Comment: Ah, not rude at all!  It's just an inconsistency between title and question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ date="2012-03-10 12:59:59"
$ read d h m s < <(IFS=:; echo $date)
$ printf -v var "%s %s:%d:00" $d $h $(( m-(m%5) ))
$ echo "$var"
2012-03-10 12:55:00
```

I use process substitution in the read command to isolate changes to IFS in a subshell.  `

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU AWK available, you could use this:

```
| gawk '{t=mktime(gensub(/[-:]/," ","g")); print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",int(t/5)*5);}'
```

This uses the `int()` function, which truncates, which sort of means "round down".  If you decide you'd prefer to "round" (i.e. go to the "nearest" 5 second increment), replace `int(t/5)` with `int((t+2.5)/5)`.

Of course, if you're feeling masochistic, you can do this in pure shell.  This one only truncates rather than rounding up.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"  
[ghoti@pc ~]$ date "+$fmt"
2012-03-15 07:53:37
[ghoti@pc ~]$ date "+$fmt" | while read date; do stamp="`date -jf \"$fmt\" \"$date\" '+%s'`"; date -r `dc -e "$stamp 5/ 5* p"` "+$fmt"; done
2012-03-15 07:53:35
```

Note that I'm using FreeBSD.  If you're using Linux, then you might need to use different options for the `date` command (in particular, the -r and -f options I think).  I'm runninB this in bash, but it should work in pure Bourne shell if that's what you need.