# processing a file using awk

Tags: awk

I am looking for awk command to change the time column of a text file to its nearest 5 minute interval. So 12:56:59 become 12:55:00

The following command works as expected. Thanks for the response.

```
head r_SERVER_2012-03-10-12-55-00 | awk -F'^' '{print $7}' |  awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d:00\n", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'
```

Correct result:

```
2012-03-10 12:55:00
```

But I want to show fields other than date as well. The following does not work:

```
head r_SERVER_2012-03-10-12-55-00 | awk -F'^' '{print $1, $2, $7, $8}' |  awk '{split($2, a, ":"); printf "%s %s:%02d:00\n", $1, a[1],int(a[2]/5)*5}'
```

Wrong result:

```
565 14718:00:00
```

It should be ...

```
565 123 2012-03-10 12:55:00 country
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round down to nearest 5 minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718047/round-down-to-nearest-5-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple awk commands, just one, and you can set awk's `FS` (field separator) variable in the script, which you can put in a file:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN {
    # all fields are separated by ^
    FS = "^";
}
{
    # $7 is the date and time in the form yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.
    # Split at colons to get hours minutes and seconds into a[1]
    # through a[3].  Round minutes to nearest 5.
    split($7, a, ":");
    a[2] = int(a[2] / 5) * 5;

    # print first and second field, then rounded time, then 8th field.
    printf "%s %s %s:%02d:00 %s\n", $1, $2, a[1], a[2], $8;
}
$ cat input
565^123^$3^$4^$5^$6^2012-03-10 12:56:59^country
$ awk -f foo.awk < input
565 123 2012-03-10 12:55:00 country
$
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. One more request... I use sed 's/\ /~/g' to replace all space with special character. Is it possible to do it in the same awk program?

Comment: Yes, use gsub() to do global substitute-and-replace.  It returns a count of replacements, which you can ignore.  For example: `gsub(" ", "~");` inserted before the final printf will replace all spaces in all fields.  Hence if `country` were `Peoples Republic of Berzerkistan` the output would be `565 123 2012-03-10 12:55:00 Peoples~Republic~of~Berzerkistan`.

Comment: gsub increased the processing time by 10 times. So not including it.